# Get content from external web page on java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a following EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeService {
    public String someOperation() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, the problem is to get content of external web page (for example `http://example.com/some/link/info.xml`) and return it. I need something like this:

```
String pageContent = SomeFancyLibrary.getPageContent(someurl);
```

Sorry if this question has been already asked here, but I didnt find any info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a file over HTTP and store its content in a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427508/how-to-download-a-file-over-http-and-store-its-content-in-a-string-in-java)

Comment: The question was to find some easier enterprise way to call external resources, not to have troubles with streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```